# How can i get the value of a selected radio button on page load and then pass it inside a div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 radio buttons with one of them checked by default. I want firstly to get the default selected/checked value of the radio button and pass it in a specific div. After that i need to change the value of the div every time the radio buttons are clicked/selected.

Below is my code but it doesn't work as it should as the `$('input[name="price"]:selected').val();` return `undefined`
What i am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```js
function calculate(prc) {
$(".popup-total-price").text(prc.value + "€");
}


var pricepopup=$('input[name="price"]:selected').val();
$(".popup-total-price").html("<span></span>" + pricepopup + "€" );
```

```css
.popup-item-size-title {
  display: inline-block;
}

.popup-total-price {
  color: red;
  margin-top: 20px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="popup-item-label ripple">
<input value="81.00" class="pp-rr" onclick="calculate(this);" type="radio" name="price" id="price" checked="checked">
<div class="popup-item-size-title">81.00€</div>                                  </label>

<label class="popup-item-label ripple">
<input value="50.00" class="pp-rr" onclick="calculate(this);" type="radio" name="price" id="price">
<div class="popup-item-size-title">50.00€</div>                                  </label>


<div class="popup-total-price"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ':checked' instead of ':selected'

```js
function calculate(prc) {
$(".popup-total-price").text(prc.value + "€");
}


var pricepopup=$('input[name="price"]:checked').val();
$(".popup-total-price").html("<span></span>" + pricepopup + "€" );
```

```css
.popup-item-size-title {
  display: inline-block;
}

.popup-total-price {
  color: red;
  margin-top: 20px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="popup-item-label ripple">
<input value="81.00" class="pp-rr" onclick="calculate(this);" type="radio" name="price" id="price" checked="checked">
<div class="popup-item-size-title">81.00€</div>                                  </label>

<label class="popup-item-label ripple">
<input value="50.00" class="pp-rr" onclick="calculate(this);" type="radio" name="price" id="price">
<div class="popup-item-size-title">50.00€</div>                                  </label>


<div class="popup-total-price"></div>
```